# Find all products of members of a set with multiplicity of factors

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sum, mathematical-optimization

Given a set of numbers `S`, how would one find all possible products of those numbers (with multiplicity of any or all factors) below a given `n`?

For example, given `S = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}, n = 12`, after sorting I would want to see:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 2^2, 5, 2*3, 7, 2^3, 3^2, 2*5, 11, 3*2^2 }
```

If the size of `S` were a known small constant, I could use:

```
int p,sum=0;
for(int i[0] = 0; p <= n; i[0]++){
  for(int i[1] = 0; p <= n; i[1]++){
    for(etc.){...
      p = pow(S[0],i[0])*pow(S[1],i[0])*pow(...
      // do what you wanted to with p here
      // in my case:
      for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_I; j++){
        if(i[j] > 0){ p *= S[i] - 1; p /= S[i]; }
      }
      sum += p;
    }
  }
}
```

But I need it to work for `S` of arbitrary size. Intuitively, it feels like a recursion problem, but I'm not sure how to begin.

One thing I should point out is that this *is* for Project Euler, so I can't get help with the maths.

Comment: Those numbers in S can be non-prime?

Comment: When I asked, I was hoping for a general solution that would work with non-primes, but now that I'm better-rested I realize that would be extremely overly-complicated to the point of not being worth it.

Comment: Divide the set of products into two mutually exclusive subsets: S1 = the set of products that include the largest number in S, and S2 = the set of products that do not. In your example, in the first category, S1 = 11 * {all the products of elements in S which are less than or equal to 12/11}, while S2 = {all the products of elements in S-{11} which are less than or equal to 12}. The growth is exponential but I can't see a faster way offhand.

Comment: @hxtk if the set only consists prime, i think it's just the famous Hamming Problem with a known fast algorithm.  I think it works as well for non-prime set except some Hamming numbers generated will be duplicated, but I cannot prove this statement so I do not write it as an answer. Anyway if the set is prime only, you can search Hamming Algorithm, with a bunch of code example in every languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can systematically build the series using a priority queue. 

The idea is to always have the smallest element yet to be produced on the top of the queue, and when you process it, add to the queue this number multiplied by all factors in S.

Pseudo code:

```
Create a priority queue (min heap) q
Add 1 to q
set last=0
while q.top() <= n:
    current = q.popHead()
    if current == last:
        continue
    last = current
    yield current
    for each x in S:
        q.add(x*current)
```

The algorithm will yield all elements which can be factored into elements in `S`, and in ascending order.

Improvement suggestions:

- Uusing a `set` to make sure no element is inserted twice to the queue, rather than the patch of using `last` I presented here.
- Note it can be improved somehow, so you won't need a priority queue,
  but only |S| queues, if |S| is fairly small, by having a regular
  queue for each factor, and when processing a number - add it to each
  of the queues multiplied by its factor.

Comment: While I don't actually no pseudo-code, I can understand almost everything you wrote... but after a quick google search I only have a vague idea what `yield` means, let alone how it translates to C++.

Comment: @hxtk It comes from python, you can think of it as a "return" that does not end the function, so if for example you have a function `foo(): yield 1; yield 2; yield 3;`, then  `foo()` is actually creating a list `[1,2,3]`. It can be translated to `C++` by creating a vector called `res`, replacing `yield(x)` with `res.append(x)`, and adding `return res` at the end of the function. Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: That cleared it up a lot. Thanks. Now I'm off to adapt it so I also get the list of distinct factors, but I'm pretty sure I've already got an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the final products, you can use a recursive function:

```
function prod(base[], n, limit) {    
    if (base.length > 0 && n <= limit) {
        process(n)
        for (i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
            prod(base[i:], n * base[i], limit)
        }
    }
}
```

This will process the products, but not in order. This is essentially your nested loop variant expressed as recursion. The recursion stops once the limit is exceeded. (The pseudocode notation `base[i:]` means the subarray from the `i`th element on to the end.)

If you need the information on the prime factors that were used and the respectie exponents, you should pass an additional array of exponents, which you must adjust for each recursive call.

Comment: There seems to be a subtle bug here: The products with `base[base.length - 1]` as a factor are never processed because of the `base.length > 0` check.

Comment: Also OP allows for a number to be used as a factor more than once, which your code does not allow.

Comment: I've introduced the shortcut bug when pseudocodifying the function. I'll fix that, thanks. (I have tested this as Python code before posting.) The code does allow a factor to be used more than once by recursing on `base[0]`, no? Anyway, I get the desired output.